# Color de celda según condiciones

Tags: python, pandas, formato, color

Tengo que pintar las celdas de una columna según relaciones que cumplen los números en la columna de al lado.
La tabla es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que he intentado, pues lo he usado para otro tipo de salidas, es el siguiente:

```
prueba_color = pd.DataFrame()
prueba_color['numero']=[1,2,3,-1,3,2,1,-1,2]

condiciones_ = [
    (prueba_color['numero']<0) & (prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)<0) & (prueba_color['numero']<prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)),
    (prueba_color['numero']<0) & (prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)<0) & (prueba_color['numero']>prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)),
    (prueba_color['numero']<0) & (prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)>0),
    (prueba_color['numero']>0) & (prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)<0),
    (prueba_color['numero']>0) & (prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)>0) & (prueba_color['numero']>prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)),
    (prueba_color['numero']>0) & (prueba_color['numero'].shift(1)>0) & (prueba_color['numero']<prueba_color['numero'].shift(1))    
]
colores_ = ['rojo1','rojo2','amarillo','azul','verde1','verde2']
prueba_color['color'] = np.select(condiciones_,colores_)
```

La idea es en lugar de escribir el nombre del color, que la celda se pinte con el color.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o error que te impide realizar lo que deseas?

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato. El problema es que no sé cómo hacerlo. He visto muchos vídeos, leído cosas, pero no logro encontrar la manera de hacer lo que necesito. Ahora estoy buscando si existe una forma de degradar colores sobre una columna en relación a los valores de ésta. Por ahora no encuentro nada parecido.